# Spring Integration Multiple Concurrent SFTP Uploads and Downloads with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am looking for direction on how best to use Spring Integration to perform multiple and concurrent SFTP uploads and downloads to different SFTP servers that are configured after the Spring Boot application running these SFTP transfers has already been started.

I need to add SFTP servers and specific file transfers dynamically. I can setup a single upload and download using pre-defined properties for a RemoteFileTemplate without any issue, but I cannot find examples or direction on how to do this dynamically and for multiple RemoteFileTemplates concurrently.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See [Dynamic TCP Client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) sample. It provides an idea how to add and remove some Spring Integration  components at runtime. In general, you need to make yourself familiar with [Dynamic Integration flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows). So, according your logic and runtime configuration you just use an `IntegrationFlowContext` to add extra `IntegrationFlow` based on additional `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` beans added to the `IntegrationFlowRegistration`.